# When we get runtime error in swift project, Why does Xcode send us to Thread output in assembly language? What's the point ?

Tags: xcode, assembly, compiler-errors, runtime-error

As you know when there is somethings wrong when we are running a Swift project in Xcode we will direct to tread debug navigator's thread section and we will be face with some assembly code like this :

[image]

[image]

I am wondering is there any reference, tutorial or tools for understanding these codes , there should be reasone that we direct to these code

let me clear; I know how to fix the errors but this suffering me when I do not understand some thing like this. I want to know what are these codes and how we can use them or at least understand them.

Thanks :)

Comment: That's AT&T syntax assembly language for x86-64.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for manuals from Intel, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info for how AT&T syntax differs from Intel syntax used in the manuals.

Comment: these are not compiler errors, the code did compile well. These are runtime errors.

Comment: So Why does Xcode send us here ? what's the point ?

Comment: The point is so you can debug your program if you know asm.  Did you compile without debug symbols?  Or did it crash in library code without symbols?  It's normal for debuggers to show you asm if it can't show you source, or if you *ask* for asm.  Did your program fault on that instruction highlighted in pink?  That's a bit odd, since it's loading from static data.  Did you maybe `munmap` or `mprotect` that static data so a load would fault?  Normally you only get faults when an addressing mode involves a pointer.

Comment: I believe majority of swift coders don't know, but anyway YES you are right, that's true, thanks

Comment: There's nothing more useful a debugger could do.  And obviously you can show the asm to someone who does understand it, or include it in a bug report.  (preferably as text, not an image of text...)  Also keep in mind that the majority of debugger authors do know asm.  Asm is what's *really* running on the machine.  Without asm, you couldn't find wrong-code compiler bugs, etc. etc.

Comment: Yes Peter this error was from pointer, again thanks for very useful comments , now I know more than before and I have some where to investigate for these kinds of errors .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original question: what language is that?  That's AT&T syntax assembly language for x86-64. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for manuals from Intel and other resources, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info for how AT&T syntax differs from Intel syntax used in most manuals.  (I think the x86 tag wiki has a few AT&T syntax tutorials.)  Most AT&T-syntax disassemblers have an intel-syntax mode, too, so you can use that if you want asm that matches Intel's manuals.

---

> What's the point?

The point is so you can debug your program if you know asm.  Or you can show the asm to someone who does understand it, or include it in a bug report.

Did you compile without debug symbols? Or did it crash in library code without symbols? It's normal for debuggers to show you asm if it can't show you source, or if you ask for asm.

If you have debug symbols for your own code, you can at least backtrace into parent functions for which you do have source. (Unless the stack is corrupted.)

---

Did your program fault on that instruction highlighted in pink? That's a bit odd, since it's loading from static data (a RIP-relative load means the address is a link-time constant).

Did you maybe `munmap` or `mprotect` that page of your program's data or text segment so a load would fault?  Normally you only get faults when an addressing mode involves a pointer.

(The `call *0x1234(%rip)` right before it is calling through a function pointer, though.  The function-pointer is stored in memory, but code-fetch after the `call` executes would fault if it was pointing to an unmapped or non-executable page).  But your first image shows you got a SIGABRT, not SIGSEGV, so that's more like the program on purpose aborted after failing an assertion.

> I believe majority of swift coders don't know asm

There's nothing more useful a debugger can do without debug symbols and source files.

Also keep in mind that the majority of debugger authors do know asm, so for them it is an obviously-useful feature / behaviour.  They know that many people won't be able to benefit from it, but that some will.

Asm is what's really running on the machine. Without asm, you couldn't find wrong-code compiler bugs, etc. etc.  As far as software bugs, there is no lower level than asm, so it's not some arbitrary choice of some lower-level layer to stop at.

(Unless there's also a bug in your disassembler or debugger, in which case you need to check the hex machine code.)